# session id null in sys.dm_os_tasks

Tags: sql-server

We are seeing parallelism causing worker thread shortage in SQL,while investigating we found session id is null for some sessions,Below is the query used.What does this session id null means ?

```
select session_id,count(*) as 'totalthreads' from sys.dm_os_tasks
group by session_id
having count(*)>1
order by totalthreads desc
```

**Output varies as below:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The session_id in sys.dm_os_tasks specify the "ID of the session that is associated with the task"   mostly it comes if your "task_state" is Done.

Answer (score 2):

The session is sleeping if the *session_id* value of [sys.dm_os_tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-tasks-transact-sql) is NULL. This is stated in the link above under the *Examples* section: Associating Session IDs with Windows threads.

> The following query does not return information for sessions that are
>   sleeping.